# Using R gsub to only return double digit characters from string?

Tags: r, regex

I have a variable that has values such as these:

```
example <- c("positive_1", "positive_2", "test_20_curve", "test_60_point", "percent_total")
```

Is there a way to only return the "20" and "60" from the vector?

I currently have

```
gsub(".*([0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", example)
```

which outputs

```
[1] "positive_1"    "positive_2"    "20"            "60"            "percent_total"
```

I'm wondering if there's a way such that any value that doesn't have a double-digit is shown as NA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about "pos_20"? "pos_200_pos"?  "\_20"? "20"? "20\_"? "pos_2_pos20_pos_200"? Are the digits always preceded by "\_"? Are the digits always at the end of the string or are followed by "\_"? Do you wish to use the regex to also confirm that the string contains only digits, underscores and lowercase letters, as in the examples? Please answer these questions and otherwise clarify by editing your question (as opposed to elaborating in comments). It's rare that you can use examples alone to ask a question  unambiguously. You need a clear statement in words. Examples are for illustration only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `stringr::str_extract` approach

You can use

```r
example <- c("positive_1", "positive_2", "test_20_curve", "test_60_point", "percent_total")
library(stringr)
str_extract(example, "(?<!\\d)\\d{2}(?!\\d)")
## => [1] NA   NA   "20" "60" NA
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/syG1hG). **Note**: `str_extract` extracts the *first* occurrence of the pattern. If you need the last one, use `library(stringi)` and then `stri_extract_last_regex(example, "(?<!\\d)\\d{2}(?!\\d)")`.

*Details*:

- `(?<!\d)` - immediately on the left, there can be no digit
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?!\d)` - not immediately followed with another digit.

### `sub` approach

```r
example <- c("positive_1", "positive_2", "test_20_curve", "test_60_point", "percent_total")
res <- sub("^(?:(?:.*\\D)?(\\d{2})(?:\\D.*)?|.+)$", "\\1", example)
res <- res[nzchar(res)]
res
## => [1] "20" "60"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/rM6cNa).

*Pattern details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - either of the two alternatives:

  - |.+)
  - `(?:.*\D)?` - an optional sequence of any non-digit char and then the rest of the string
  - `(\d{2})` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value): two digits
  - `(?:\D.*)?` - an optional sequence of any non-digit char and then the rest of the string
- `|` - or

  - `.+` - one or more chars as many as possible
- `)` - end of the outer grouping (so that either pattern part could match the whole string)
- `$` - end of string.

Note `sub` is enough here since we perform a single replacement when the whole string is matched.

If there is no 2-digit number only in the string, the result of the `sub` will be an empty string, so we need to use `res <- res[nzchar(res)]` to get rid of them.

**NOTE**: If there are more than one occurrences of 2-digit numbers, the last one is returned using this approach. To get the first one, use `sub("^(?:(?:.*?\\D)?(\\d{2})(?:\\D.*)?|.+)$", "\\1", example, perl=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

With `gsub` we first extract the double-digit numbers
then with `grepl` we check for a double-digit number in each element of the vector and
replace the others with NA

```
example <- c("positive_1", "positive_2", "test_20_curve", "test_60_point", "percent_total")

x <- gsub(".*?([0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", example)
x[!grepl("[0-9]{2}", example)] <- NA

x
```

```
[1] NA   NA   "20" "60" NA
```

Comment: Extracting the digits twice looks a bit too weird to me. It should be a bit inefficient at least. Why not go with a simpler `nchar` solution in step #2?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
example <- c(
  "positive_1", 
  "positive_2", 
  "test_20_curve", 
  "test_60_point",
  "percent_total"
  )

res <- sub("^\\D+(\\d{2})?\\D.*$", "\\1", example)

res[grepl("^$", res)] <- NA

res
```

Outputs:

```
[1] NA   NA   "20" "60" NA
```

`\\D+` test for non-digits followed by

`(\\d{2})` two digits, that are captured followed by

`\\D*` any number of non-digits, ensuring that no more than two digits are matched.

Everything is matched and only the captured two digits are replaced.

`NA` is inserted for any empty string.